# How to dynamically apply CSS in vue.js?

Tags: css, vue.js

This is my situation:

I have a web app that allow users to change the UI size. (i.e. small, medium or large button)

Users can change how it looks like dynamically during runtime. All text and form input boxes will be resized.

My project is in Vue.js.

What is the best way to solve this?  Loading different css when user click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load different CSS while user click the button similar to this .  Codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NJEoVM

HTML

```
    <div id="app" :class="size">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
  <input class="ipt"/><br/><br/> 
  <button class="btn" @click="change('small')">Small</button>
  <button class="btn"  @click="change('medium')">Medium</button>
  <button class="btn"  @click="change('large')">Large</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .small .ipt{
  width: 100px;
  height:30px;
}
.small .text{
  font-size: 18px;
}

.medium .ipt{
  width: 300px;
  height:50px;
}
.medium .text{
  font-size: 32px;
}

.large .ipt{
  width: 600px;
  height:100px;
}
.large .text{
  font-size: 64px;
}
```

Javascript

```
    new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:()=>({
  size:'small'
}),
methods:{
  change(val){
    this.size = val
  }
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks. that's a pretty straight forward way.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can make use of [Custom Properties aka CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).

Firstly, define the button CSS styles

```css
   /* button.css */
   #buttonRef {
     --fontSize: 16px;
     font-size: var(--fontSize)
    }
```

The overall flow would be something like the following one e.g

```
methods: {
  changeButtonSize: function(size, event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    /* size might be either of 's', 'm', 'l' */

    /* let the button ref is stored in refs */

    const buttonRef = this.$refs[“buttonRef”];

    let fontSize = 16;

    switch(size) {
      case 's':
        fontSize = 12;
      case 'm':
        fontSize = 18;
      case 'l':
        fontSize = 22;
    }

    /* dynamically change the value for custom property */
    buttonRef.style.setProperty("--fontSize", fontSize);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set up 3 classes:

```
.small {font-size:12px}
.medium {font-size:18px}
.large {font-size:24px}
```

Then add or remove them to your main parent div onClick.

If you have discreetly set the font-size on the elements, you'll have to target those elements as such:

```
.small .description { font-size:12px }
.small .title{ font-size:16px }
```